# How to make compose AlertDialog Rtl?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to change a composable's direction like AlertDialog's content based on device locale?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `LayoutDirection` like this:

```
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {
        ...
    }
```

and you can change `LayoutDirection.Rtl` vs `LayoutDirection.Ltr` based on the locale, which you can get from

```
LocalContext.current.resources.configuration.locales
```

Comment: Thank you user496854 !   
I use your answer with some changes in my answer .
Your answer is not completed . I complete it in my answer .

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74970703/11819708

Answer (score 0):

implement material3 :

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1'
```

Use this function with material3 library ( *You can use another material versions with material3 together. but you can't use older material libraries to make a rtl alert dialog* ) :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AlertDialogWithDirection(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    confirmButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dismissButton: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    icon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    title: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    text: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = AlertDialogDefaults.shape,
    containerColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.containerColor,
    iconContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.iconContentColor,
    titleContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.titleContentColor,
    textContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.textContentColor,
    tonalElevation: Dp = AlertDialogDefaults.TonalElevation,
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties()
) {
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest,
        confirmButton = {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides layoutDirection) {
                confirmButton()
            }
        },
        modifier,
        {
            if (dismissButton != null)
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides layoutDirection) {
                    dismissButton()
                }
        },
        icon,
        {
            if (title != null)
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides layoutDirection) { title() }
        },
        {
            if (text != null)
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides layoutDirection) { text() }
        },
        shape,
        containerColor,
        iconContentColor,
        titleContentColor,
        textContentColor,
        tonalElevation,
        properties
    )
}
```

And use like this :

```kotlin
AlertDialogWithDirection(
    onDismissRequest = { 

    },
    title = {
        Text(
            text = "Your Text"
        )
    },
    text = {
        Text(
            text = "Your Text"
        )
    },
    confirmButton = {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                ok()
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Button"
            )
        }
    },
    dismissButton = {
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = { 
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Dismiss")
        }
    }
)
```